# Script Python funcionando como um serviço no servidor (Oracle Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, servidor

Bom dia pessoal,

Tenho um pequeno script em python que examina arquivos do formato .xml enviados automaticamente de clientes para um compartilhamento. Meu script, examina e extrai dados deles para um Banco de Dados.

Mas como esse compartilhamento é aberto, só pode haver arquivos desse tipo e com a formatação correta. Até aqui obtive bastante êxito, mas só quando eu executo o script "na mão".
O problema foi quando idealizei por esse script funcionando como um serviço, tipo systemctl start "nome do serviço". Daí o que eu executava via terminal e concluia com ótima performance e desempenho,teve um resultado diferente, ou seja, nem sempre funcionava. Segue o código:

```
`#!/usr/bin/env python3

#função tempo
import time
#monitoramento da pasta
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class NewFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        import shutil
        if event.is_directory:
            print(event.src_path, "é um diretório e será apagado")
            shutil.rmtree(event.src_path)
        else:
            arquivo = (event.src_path)
            print("Um novo arquivo foi adicionado:", event.src_path)
            time.sleep(0.4)
            magic(arquivo)

# VERIFICA SE O ARQUIVO É UM ARQUIVO DO TIPO XML
def magic(arquivo):
    #verifica o magic number dos arquivos
    import magic
    import os
    #LÊ E VERIFICA SE É UM ARQUIVO XML
    with open(arquivo, "rb") as f:
        magic_number = f.read(5).decode()
        if magic_number == "<?xml":
            print("Arquivo XML")
            lexml(arquivo)
        else:
            #print(arquivo, "será apagado")
            os.remove(arquivo)

def lexml(arquivo):
    #ler XML
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
    #resgata data atual
    from datetime import date
    #comandos de sistema operacional
    import os
    data_atual = date.today()
    #VERIFICA SE A SINTAXE DO ARQUIVO ESTÁ CORRETA
    try:
        xml = et.parse(arquivo)
        raiz = xml.getroot()
        print("O arquivo XML está com sintaxe correta!")
          try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user=os.environ.get("USER_DB"),
                                    password= os.environ.get("PWD_DB"),
                                    host="192.168.0.1",
                                    port="5432",
                                    database="bd_postgres")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        #LEITURA DOS CAMPOS DA TABELA COMPRADOR
        for camposcomprador in raiz.findall('compradores'):
            nome = camposclientes.find('name').text.strip()
            endereco = camposclientes.find('endereco').text.strip()
            e-mail  = camposcllientes.find('email').text.strip()
            conta_corrente = camposclientes.find('conta').text.strip()
          
        if nome == None:
            try:
                observer.join()
            except:
                observer.join()
        else:
            #DIRECIONA PARA INSERT INTO
            select_bd = """SELECT id FROM cliente WHERE nome = %s"""
            cursor.execute( select_bd, (nome,))
            select_id = cursor.fetchone()
            count_consulta = cursor.rowcount
            if select_id == None:
                print("Faz um INSERT into")
                insert_cliente = """INSERT INTO clientes (nome, endereco, e-mail, conta_corrente, time_stamp)VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) returning id"""
                cursor.execute( insert_cliente, (nome, enderco, e-mail, conta_corrente, data_atual))
                connection.commit()
                count_insert = cursor.rowcount
                print(count_insert, "registro inserido")
                
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            print("Erro:", error)

    finally:
    # fechando a conexão
        if connection:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("A conexão PostgreSQL foi encerrada")
            
except et.ParseError as e:
    # Se ocorrer um erro de análise, o arquivo não está com sintaxe correta
    print("Erro de sintaxe no arquivo XML:", e)

os.remove(arquivo)

#####################################################################

observer = Observer()
event_handler = NewFileHandler()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/compartilhamento', recursive=True)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu consegui resolver atribuindo as variáveis de ambientes, que trazem o usuário e a senha do Banco de dados no arquivo UNIT,em /etc/systemd/system/lexml.service, que gera o serviço.
Através da diretiva "Enviroment".

```
[Unit]
Description=LEXML
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script.py
Restart=always
User=root
Group=wheel
WorkingDirectory=/compartilhamento
Environment="PWD_DB"=123456 ""USER_DB"=user"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```